# What is the best way to get specific object inside array of objects in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm creating inside a service array of dynamic objects. I would like any controller to use that service and get a specific object inside that array.

I must run a for loop in order to find that object? 
Any better and fast way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is pretty vague, but in the service you could create a map of (id -> object) instead of an array. Then getting an object with a specific id becomes simple.

Comment: Where can I find info about creating map inside Angularjs service?

Comment: Just a regular javascript variable
    var map = {};
    map[object.id] = object;